# puppetlabs' file_line type not working

Tags: puppet

I've been working on learning puppet and using it to set up a jenkins box. I'm wiring jenkins through tomcat, since I may also end up running other webapps on there.

**EDIT**: I've installed (via `puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib`) the stdlib provided by puppetlabs to use the file_line type.

This is puppet module manifest for setting up jenkins and tomcat and wiring the two together.

```
class tomcat_jenkins {
  package{'java-1.7':
    ensure => installed,
    name   => 'java-1.7.0-openjdk',
  }

  package{'tomcat6':
    ensure  => installed,
    require => Package['java-1.7'],
  }

  package{'jenkins':
    ensure  => installed,
    require => Yumrepo['jenkins'],
  }

  file{'jenkins-symlink':
    name    => '/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/jenkins.war',
    require => [Package['tomcat6'], Package['jenkins']],
    ensure  => link,
    target  => '/usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war',
  }

  file{ '/srv':
    ensure => directory,
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
  }

  file{ '/srv/jenkins':
    ensure  => directory,
    owner   => 'tomcat',
    group   => 'tomcat',
    require => Package['tomcat6'],
  }

  file_line{'jenkins_home':
    ensure  => present,
    path    => '/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf',
    line    => 'JENKINS_HOME=/srv/jenkins',
    require => [Package['tomcat6'], File['/srv/jenkins']],
  }

  service{'tomcat6':
    ensure    => running,
    enable    => true,
    require   => [Package['tomcat6'], Package['jenkins'], File_line['jenkins_home']],
    subscribe => [Package['jenkins'], File['jenkins-symlink']],
  }

}
```

I see the output from the puppet agent that it is properly applying the catalog, and it pretends like it went ahead and applied the changes, but there's no `/jenkins/` in my /etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf file. I don't have anything else managing that file.

`puppet agent -t -d` output:

```
info: Applying configuration version '1343250206'
debug: /Stage[main]/Tomcat_jenkins/File_line[jenkins_home]/require: requires Package[tomcat6]
debug: /Stage[main]/Tomcat_jenkins/File_line[jenkins_home]/require: requires File[/srv/jenkins]
debug: /Stage[main]/Epel_repo/Yumrepo[epel]/require: requires File[/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6]
debug: /Stage[main]/Tomcat_jenkins/Package[jenkins]/require: requires Yumrepo[jenkins]
debug: /Stage[main]/Tomcat_jenkins/Service[tomcat6]/require: requires Package[tomcat6]
debug: /Stage[main]/Tomcat_jenkins/Service[tomcat6]/require: requires Package[jenkins]
debug: /Stage[main]/Tomcat_jenkins/Service[tomcat6]/require: requires File_line[jenkins_home]
debug: /Stage[main]/Tomcat_jenkins/Service[tomcat6]/subscribe: subscribes to Package[jenkins]
debug: /Stage[main]/Tomcat_jenkins/Service[tomcat6]/subscribe: subscribes to File[jenkins-symlink]
```

Comment: Where are you finding that `file_line` is a valid resource?  It doesn't appear as a standard resource type on the official documentation.  http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html

Comment: Sorry, it comes from the puppetlabs/stdlib module: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib Which I have `puppet module install`ed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Asking around on #puppet on irc.freenode.net, I found out that I was missing a configuration parameter on the puppet agent. I needed:

```
pluginsync=true
```

in the `[main]` section. After adding that line, it happily downloaded the plugins, and set up my stuff. Win.

Comment: You can also use `--pluginsync` if you're messing on the command line.